# Tomb Raider (2013) goes black

Tags: steam, technical-issues, tomb-raider-2013

I decided to play Tomb Raider today for sense a few months ago. When i clicked play on the launcher all I got was a black screen. I have tried changing the resolution and the exclusive full screen option, which I read would help solve this problem but did not. How can I fix this? Do I have to reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. try to go to steam then right click on the game the select properties then select verify integrity of game cache. If not id recommend contacting steam support or a re-install

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I'll try reinstalling.